# How to show the previous month in Razor syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

Please see my Razor syntax sample below. I'm trying to get the last month as a string. For example, the below code gives me "November 2020", but I am trying to get "October 2020"

```html
<p class="card-text">Click here for the latest budget for <b>@((DateTime.Now).ToString("MMMM")) @DateTime.Now.Year</b></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like below:

```
<p class="card-text">Click here for the latest budget for <b>@((DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)).ToString("MMMM")) @DateTime.Now.Year</b></p>
```